# How to access an html object on another page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

my problem is that I want to get access from page `index1.html` to object in page `index2.html`, for example:

`<button id="btnIndex1" onclick="$('#PopUpDIvIdInPageIndex2').show();">btn in index1.html</button>`

Solutions with coockies and another storages are not useful for me because I need immediately(real-time) access.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just reference an element on another page. What would happen if you could just inject some code this way in a `div` on the open Facebook page from a user? That wouldn't be nice, huh.

The option you have in my opinion to make this semi-real-time is by using WebSockets. From page 1, send a request to the server. The server will send a request to page 2 to update something.

To learn more about WebSockets, read this tutorial on [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/).

Answer (score 0):

For a simple task to load a page from a click event I would instead suggest an ajax-request.

This could simply be done with the javascript library jquery.

http://jquery.com/

Have a look at the jquery load method

http://api.jquery.com/load/